# JVM crash suddenly

Tags: java, dll, jvm

I have a simple javaFx application that worked a month ago perfectly.
Today i tried to run it and after a second the app crash and the windows say the Java has stopped, when i open the debugger it show me this message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFEC849349D (CompPkgSup.dll) in javaw.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
```

I tried to reboot my computer and update the JDK but without any success, also run the eclipse with administrator privileges also without success.
Computer details: windows 10 64 bit, JDK jdk1.8.0_121 64 bit (tried also with jdk1.8.0_91 64 bit), eclipse neon.1 64 bit version.

Comment: That's a windows media player file. Have you checked for recent windows updates which might have changed this file?

Comment: Also, look at this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-media-player-exception-fails-with-code/ec3f0c51-309f-4fe3-8c52-c95b4f40d978 Might be related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Java issue, since the error is coming from a DLL.
Apparently at least Windows 10 has had issues due to a bad update related to codecs: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/5zw5r3/heads_up_windows_10_kb4013429_makes_applications/

I'd imagine it's related, even if you're not on Win10.